# Complex Conjugation problem using the identity $|x|^2=xx^*$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value

Show that $$|c|^2= \frac{4k^2}{k^2 +\gamma^2}$$ given (1)$$a+b=c$$ and (2)$$ik(a-b)=-\gamma c$$ This was given in a lecture without proof, so there's probably a very simple way of proving the equality. This is a purely algebraic problem.

Using (1) and (2) I can show that $$b=a(\frac{k-i\gamma}{k+i\gamma})$$ and similarly $$a=b(\frac{k+i\gamma}{k-i\gamma})$$ Which leads me to $$|b|^2=bb^*=a^*(\frac{k+i\gamma}{k-i\gamma})a(\frac{k-i\gamma}{k+i\gamma})=aa^*=|a|^2$$
**Where $i=\sqrt-1$, $k$ and $\gamma$ are unknowns; $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real constants.**

My attempt at showing the top relation was to take the complex conjugate of (2) for $c$ such that $$c=-\frac{ik(a-b)}{\gamma}$$ and $$c^*=\frac{ik(a-b)}{\gamma}$$ and then using the identity $$|c|^2=cc^*$$ and eliminating $a$ and $b$ but still unable to get the desired result.

Could someone please show me step by step how to obtain $$|c|^2= \frac{4k^2}{k^2 +\gamma^2}$$

Thank you.

Comment: I assume $k$ and $\gamma$ are real? Are there any other constraints?

Comment: And have you tried actual values of these numbers, just to see what happens? What about $k = \gamma = 1$, $a = 2$, $b = -2i$, $c = 2 - 2i$...?

Comment: @AlexZorn Thanks for your reply, they can be real or complex it doesn't matter here, the result was just given to me in a lecture without proof so there is probably something very simple that I am missing. The relation I'm trying to prove isn't an identity so I haven't tried any values.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe your edit. First of all, why would the expression read $|c|^2$ if $c$ were real? Second, your computation of $a^{*}$ suggests that you think $a$ might be a complex number, and the fact that $k^{*}$ and $\gamma^{*}$ don't appear in your computation at all implies that you think $k$ and $\gamma$ are real.

Comment: @AlexZorn This question is purely about algebraic manipulation, it doesn't matter whether $k$ and $\gamma$ are real or otherwise, in the quantum physics lecture we were not told about whether these quantities were real or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use the first equation to eliminate $b$. Then:

$$ik(2a - c) = -\gamma c$$

$$c = \frac{2ik}{ik - \gamma}a$$

Multiply by $-ik - \gamma$:

$$c = \frac{k - i\gamma}{k^2 + \gamma^2}2ka$$

Now we compute:

$$|c|^2 = \frac{k^2 + \gamma^2}{(k^2 + \gamma^2)^2} \cdot 4k^2|a|^2 = \frac{4k^2}{k^2 + \gamma^2}|a|^2$$

So I'm guessing $|a| = 1$, otherwise your identity is not true. (I've also assumed $k$ and $\gamma$ are real and not both zero, otherwise the expression $\frac{4k^2}{k^2 + \gamma^2}$ might not be negative or have an imaginary component which wouldn't make sense)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however $|a|$ is real just like $b$ and $c$ and their moduli, but the modulus of $a$ may not be 1.